# setcookie doesn't work on linux

Tags: php, cookies

I recently installed centos(linux) on my pc. I have a piece of code in which setcookie function is used for displaying a message. It works perfectly on all other windows pcs connected in a network. I have no clue about what is wrong. Is there need of any additional parameter to be applied in setcookie function for linux?

The code I applied is as follows:

```
    setcookie("msg","This record already exist",time()+5,"/");
    header("location:".SITE."index.php?page=inventory_sub_categoryfrm);
    exit;
```

and `isset($_COOKIE['msg'])` returns false.

Http header:

```
    Request URL:http://192.168.1.39/ems/abc.php
    Request Method:GET
    Status Code:200 OK
    Request Headers
    Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
    Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
    Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
    Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
    Cache-Control:max-age=0
    Connection:keep-alive
    Cookie:PHPSESSID=8q10m0jc8c49eneo924udm2093
    Host:192.168.1.39
    User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko)        

    Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31
    Response Headers
    Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
    Connection:close
    Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
    Date:Thu, 23 May 2013 10:00:09 GMT
    Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
    Pragma:no-cache
    Server:Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
    Transfer-Encoding:chunked
    X-Powered-By:PHP/5.5.0RC1
```

Comment: Is linux your server or client?

Comment: I think it may depend on you browser?

Comment: check browser settings? Are browser and server on the same pc?

Comment: @AleksG Linux is my server and client is windows. But it doesn't work on none of them. Jeff. Nope, It worked perfectly when I was using it on windows server. Robert Browser and server are not on the same pc. Client browser settings are perfect. There is nothing wrong with them.

Comment: look at the header returned by the server in your browser's dev tools, and all them to the question

Comment: @Lepidosteus it includes <meta> <link> and <script> tags. What should I do?

Comment: @Harit — The HTTP header, not the HTML `<head>` element.

Comment: Can u please explain me how to check http header??  is that tools-> developer tools -> resources -> cookie ??

Comment: Tools -> developer tools -> Net

Comment: In request header I get Cookie:PHPSESSID=8q10m0jc8c49eneo924udm2093

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo, you forgot a double quote:

```
header("location:".SITE."index.php?page=inventory_sub_categoryfrm);
//                                                       here ---^
```

Also the cookie lifetime is too short, you're giving it 5 seconds by using `time()+5`, so please give it a longer life span `time()+86400`.

Comment: I tried longer life span as well.. No it's not a typo.. In hurry I didn't type it perfectly.. I closed the quotes mahn.. Any other suggestion?

Comment: @Harit Try `var_dump(setcookie(your code));`, does it return true or false ?

Comment: print_r($_COOKIE) returns PHPSESSID together with its value

Comment: @Harit just a question, have you tried this code on an *empty* page ?

Comment: it returns true on an empty page

Comment: @Harit ok, in your code, what if you removed the header part ? And use `print_r($_COOKIE);` instead. Open/Refresh that page twice.

Comment: Dude, can u pls Explain me about http header? i checked from chrome dev tools that in request header Cookie:PHPSESSID=8q10m0jc8c49eneo924udm2093

Comment: in addition, if I set cookie(say for example msg) from another empty page and access it, request header shows that cookie msg value as well.

Comment: @Harit lol there is nothing to explain about, it is clear: there is a "cookie" with name "PHPSESSID" and value "8q10m0jc8c49eneo924udm2093". You have something that conflicts with the setcookie otherwise it wouldn't work on an empty page. It's up to you to debug this matter since I can't read the code you have.